# How to change TextView background color when touching in and out of view?

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener

This has to be a very simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have got my program to change the background color to change `onClick`, and onTouch with `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`. But I need it to change the color when touching the screen and going in and out of the `TextView`. I need it to function like a mouseOver/mouseOut event. Is there a way to do this on android? Or am I stuck with `onTouch`, where the action has to start from within the `TextView`?

Right now I set the `onTouchListener` on the `TextView` itself. Should I set it somewhere else and then check if the x and y are within the `Textview`? Or is there another event listener I should be using? I am new to Android, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement the `OnTouchListener` on your application and then on the `onTouch` method, keep checking if the current position of the touch event is within the bounds of the *bounding box* of the view. If it is, apply the new background and if it isn't apply the original one.

Since all the views implement the `setBackgroundColor` I didn't do any casting to `TextView` but the example should suffice, at least as a starting point to develop your application further.

The full code for this is the following:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Set the listener for the parent/container view
        findViewById(R.id.cont).setOnTouchListener(this);

        //Get a hold of the view and create the Rect for the bounds
        View target = findViewById(R.id.target);
        Rect b = new Rect();

        //Get the bounding box of the target view into `b`
        target.getGlobalVisibleRect(b);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        //Check if it's within the bounds or not
        if(b.contains((int)event.getRawX(),(int) event.getRawY())){
            target.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
        }else{
            target.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
        }

        //You need to return true to keep on checking the event
        return true;
    }
}
```

As for the user interface for the previous code, it's just a linear layout with an ID `cont` and a view (a `TextView` in your case) with an ID `target`. The rest is totally by default so there is no point in me pasting it here. **Note** I only tested this on an emulator and *ymmv* when trying it on real devices, but as far as I can think of, it should be fine.

---

**Relevant documentation:**

- [getGlobalVisibleRect method](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3AAndroid.Views.View.GetGlobalVisibleRect(Android.Graphics.Rect%2CAndroid.Graphics.Point))
- [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Comment: Probably should declare `b` outside the `onCreate` method. Just saying.

Comment: What is t and where did you declare it? It should be a rect right?!