# TextView onTouchListener not working?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have implemented a customer on touch listener that is supposed to change the color of the textview when a user touches the textview and change it back to the default color when the finger is released.

```
public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1089F9"));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AA000000"));
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


final TextView basicDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.basicdetailstitle);
basicDetails.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());
```

The color changes to blue (#1089F9) when touched, however it doesn't change back to default (#AA000000) when the finger is released. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556472/how-to-change-textview-background-color-when-touching-in-and-out-of-view ? Didn't try but seems good...Also in your example, I think you should return true in onTouch(..) method to keep the system sending you events...

Comment: Have you considered using a selector? Provides way more flexibility than what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always return false on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` you wont receive the  following events.

You can achieve want you want by using a selector:

create a new xml in like:  res/color/myselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#1089F9" /> 
     <item android:color="#AA000000" /> 
</selector>
```

In your layout add the following to your TextView:

```
android:textColor="@color/myselector"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Return true and you are done

[Follow this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)